# Statistical hypothesis testing: 2 normal distributions with different mean and different variance

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Let consider 2 hypotheses
$$\begin{cases}
\mathcal{H}_{0}: & \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_{0},\sigma_{0}^{2}\right)\\
\mathcal{H}_{1}: & \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_{1},\sigma_{1}^{2}\right)
\end{cases}, $$
where $\mu_{0}$, $\sigma_{0}^{2}$, $\mu_{1}$, $\sigma_{1}^{2}$ are known, and $\mu_{0}\neq \mu_1$, $\sigma^2_0 \neq \sigma^2_1$ . Can we use the fundamental lemma by Neyman and Pearson to test these hypotheses? If not, do you have any suggestion?

Thanks you in advance for your answer.

%%%%%% Edit %%%%%%%

I edit my question as commented by WarreG and BruceET.

I have a set of i.i.d. samples. I know that these samples follow either $\mathcal{N}(\alpha_0,\sigma^2_0)$ or $\mathcal{N}(\alpha_1,\sigma^2_1)$ (i.e., only one of them). I would like to use statistical hypothesis testing to detect the probability distribution of this samples set. Actually, when {$\mu_{0}\neq \mu_1$ and $\sigma^2_0 = \sigma^2_1$} or when {$\mu_{0}= \mu_1$ and $\sigma^2_0 \neq \sigma^2_1$}, I know how to do the test for the detection. But it strange when {$\mu_{0}\neq \mu_1$ and $\sigma^2_0 \neq \sigma^2_1$}.

Comment: Are you testing that these two distributions are compatible with eachother? Or do you want to test if $H_0$ is invalid and should take $H_1$ as a better hypothesis?

Comment: To test $H_0: \mu_0 = \mu_1$ vs $\ne$, the standard test not assuming $\sigma_0^2 = \sigma_1^2$ is the Welch (separate variances) two-sample t test. // To test whether the two samples have different normal distributions (differing in mean or variance or both) is messier. (I seem to recall this situation was discussed in an article in _The American Statistician_ a few years ago. I'll take a quick look and update this comment if I can find it; otherwise, maybe try your own search skills.) // Anyhow, please clarify your Question.

Comment: Thank you WarreG and BruceET. Please let me clarify my question. I have a set of idd samples. I know that these samples follow either $\mathcal{N}(\alpha_0,\sigma^2_0)$ or $\mathcal{N}(\alpha_1,\sigma^2_1)$. I would like to use statistical hypothesis testing to detect the probability distribution of this samples set. Actually, when {$\mu_{0}\neq \mu_1$ and $\sigma^2_0 = \sigma^2_1$} or when {$\mu_{0}= \mu_1$ and $\sigma^2_0 \neq \sigma^2_1$}, I know how to do the test for the detection. But it strange when {$\mu_{0}\neq \mu_1$ and $\sigma^2_0 \neq \sigma^2_1$}. Thank you for your help!